# Read claims in SecurityToken C#

Tags: c#, jwt

I have a access token from OAuth 2.0 which is encrypted using JwtSecurityTokenHandler.WriteToken(). After i decrypt it using JwtSecurityTokenHandler.ReadToken(), it returns me SecurityToken Object but i do not know how to loop and read the claim inside the decrypted token.

There is ways to read claim in JwtSecurityToken but unfortunately read token returns SecurityToken instead of JwtSecurityToken.

Hope someone could help.

Comment: I don't know the code or classes, but I'd guess JwtSecurityToken implements / extends SecurityToken, and there's a good chance you're actually being returned a JwtSecurityToken from the API. Can you cast or `as` the result to a JwtSecurityToken?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You should be able to cast it as a `JwtSecurityToken`:

```
var jwt = jwtSecurityTokenHandler.ReadToken(tokenString) as JwtSecurityToken;
```

Comment: that's throw exception if we don't have valid signature

Comment: Why would you have an invalid signature ?